# How document an API that produces a file (pdf) for download on Swagger?

Tags: spring, rest, api, swagger

I'm trying to discover some way to document an API that returns a PDF (or any other file) to download.

Using Spring, my Rest resource is like this:

```
@Override
@GetMapping(produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> find(
        @PathVariable long id
) {

    Result result = service.find(id);

    HttpHeaders headers = disableCache();

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentLength(result.getSize())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(result.getFileInputStream()));
}
```

This works very well to download the file. But I don't know the good practice to document the response using Swagger.

Actually, I tried that with Swagger annotations:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Some description")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success.")
})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@GetMapping(produces = "application/pdf")
ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> find(
        @PathVariable long id
);
```

But the Swagger returns the content of `InputStreamResource` as Json on Swagger-ui, what is **not** the result.

How represent a file download on the response for Swagger?

Answer (score 2):

Let try to update your code like this:

1. Update headers:

```
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
```

2. Use this annotation:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success.", response = byte.class)
})
```

3. Update the pom:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works*

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF.toString());
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + name + ".pdf");

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));

Answer (score 0):

The annotations were ignored, but this worked for me:

```
TypeResolver typeResolver = new TypeResolver();
new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
    .alternateTypeRules(AlternateTypeRules.newRule(
        typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, InputStreamResource.class),
        typeResolver.resolve(Byte.class), 
        DIRECT_SUBSTITUTION_RULE_ORDER));
```